# How to change the amount accordingly to the quantity in cart in android?

Tags: android, listview

### I have two Button + and - when i click on the + button the value increases in the textview and vice versa. but i want to multiply the textview number to the price and change the price accordingly.

```
viewHolder.mBtnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                PojoCategory pojoCategory = (PojoCategory) v.getTag();
                int mValue = pojoCategory.getmQuantity();
                mValue++;
                viewHolder.tv_Number.setText("" + mValue);
                pojoCategory.setmQuantity(mValue);

                String value1 = viewHolder.tv_Number.getText().toString();
                String value2 = pojoCategory.getDish_rate();
                Log.e("value1", value1);
                Log.e("value2", value2);

                int x = Integer.parseInt(value1);
                int y = Integer.parseInt(value2);


                int z = x * y;

                Log.e("z", "" + z);


                 viewHolder.Dish_rate.setText(String.valueOf(z));


                notifyDataSetChanged();


            }
        });
```

Comment: What I understood for your question is that problem :  You have ListView and it is not updating even after calling notifyDataSetChanged()??? Please correct me If I am wrong.

Comment: No,the problem is when i click on the + button the price change accordingly to the quantity.but when i again pressed the + button the price getting the last price and change accordingly to it.and i want to making the price constant and when i multiply with the quantity it change accodingly.but when muliply next time again the price i will get which i geeting first.

Comment: Actually I am not able to understand it can you please add a example to your question saying precisely what is happening now and what should happen ideally?. My other doubt, are you sure that you are not using ListView/RecyclerView?

Comment: Dear sir,i am using listview.and i will explain you the whole procedure.i have a cart.which have two button + and - and two textview one is for the item quantity and other is for the item price.i am getting item price from the server. then when i click on the + button the quantity increses and then i getting the quantity and multiply with the item price.and show the price at the same textview it works fine.but when i do this step again the item price updated.but i want to make item price constant.which i have getting from the server.please give me any solution if you have.thanks in advance.

Comment: your comment : "but when i do this step again the item price updated.but i want to make item price constant.which i have getting from the server." then instead of multiplying it with quantity directly set the value of price in the TextView. And use the multiplying logic in the cart total amount.

Comment: yes,you are right.i am doing directly set the value of price in the textview.but when i mulitply with the quantity i want to show the price in the same textview again.then when i getting the value from the price textview is the total amount.but i want the price which i am getting from the server.now tell me are you understand me or not ??

Comment: for this as mentioned earlier you can keep the price amount constant by removing multiplying logic from current location to location where you are doing total amount. OR you can divide the total price by the quantity which would give you the actual price.

Comment: thanks i understood the logic.what you are trying to tell me .thanks @ShadowDroid can you give me your watsapp number if you don't mind.because i am new in android. and i want to help of senior like you.